# Trying to transpile a js file in wpf c# project

Tags: c#, node.js, wpf, babeljs

I'm attempting to call Process.Start to invoke Babel and transpile a js file in my c# project.

I've installed babel into a directory "ES6" using the command:

npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev

the directory C:\ES6\node_modules.bin now has a babel and babel.cmd file

Now I'm attempting to transpile a js file using Process.Start and redirecting the std out to capture the results I can use:

```
        string babelFileName = @"C:\ES6\node_modules\.bin\babel";
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
            FileName = babelFileName,
            Arguments =  " --presets es2015 " + ViewModel.EditorViewModel.JSFullFilePath,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        };

        string js = ViewModel.EditorViewModel.Javascript;
        using (var process = Process.Start(startInfo)) {
            var standardOutput = new StringBuilder();

            // read chunk-wise while process is running.
            while (!process.HasExited) {
                standardOutput.Append(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            }

            int exitCode = process.ExitCode;

            // make sure not to miss out on any remaindings.
            standardOutput.Append(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

            string stdout = standardOutput.ToString();
            js = string.IsNullOrEmpty(stdout) ? js : stdout;
        }
```

I've tried to invoke bable using "bable." to get around the missing ".exe" extension but no luck. I get the following exception:

The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.

Hoping someone can point out how I can properly invoke babel to do this.

**UPDATE

I took a look at babel.cmd since this command line does transpile correctly:

C:\ES6\node_modules.bin>babel someES5.js --presets es2015

babel.cmd:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\..\babel-cli\bin\babel.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\..\babel-cli\bin\babel.js" %*
)
```

And modified my C#:

```
string babeljs = @"C:\ES6\node_modules\babel-cli\bin\babel.js";
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
                FileName = "node.exe",
                Arguments = babeljs + " " + ViewModel.EditorViewModel.JSFullFilePath,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };
```

This does essentially echo the un-transpiled js code verbatim. If I now add " --presets es2015 " to the arguments, the process completes successfully but with empty output.

What do I need to add here to get transpiled js from this node.exe process?

Comment: Babel has an api for c#. https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation

Comment: Yes, I've installed bable via node and have verified I can run the above from the windows command line - I just need to make it work from inside my c# app

Comment: Also, I'm not able to install all of React.net into my project. It ins't an asp.net project anyway.